# Specify the yaxis length separately from the drawing limits in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to specify the `yaxis` line length independently of the drawing distance in matplotlib?

I currently use something like that to generate the figure

```
# -- We plot the data
figSpectrum   = plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
axSpectrum    = figSpectrum.add_subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

input_spec,   = plt.plot(x, yTheo, color='#ee923b', lw=2, label='Input spectrum')
samples_spec, = plt.plot(x, ySamples, 'o', ms=1, color='k', label='Samples')

axSpectrum.set_ylim((0.0,1.0))
```

where `yTheo` and `ySamples` are in the set `[0,1]`. When I use `axSpectrum.set_ylim((0.0,1.0))`, the lineplot gets clipped like in the figure below (clipped area is shown in the red rectangle). 
[image: The top portion of the lineplot gets clipped.]

However, if I use `axSpectrum.set_ylim((0,1.1))`, then the y-axis is goes beyond the 1.0 tick, which I find annoying (see below). Is there a way to tell matplotlib to draw the lineplots from `y=0` to `y=1.1` while drawing the yaxis from `y=0` to `y=1`?

[image: The yaxis extends too far above the last tick at y=1.0]

Comment: Have you tried setting clip_on to False for the plt.plot calls?

Comment: No. I guess I was using the wrong Google search terms. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `clip_on=False` as an option to `plt.plot`. This will allow the lines drawn by `plot` to go outside the axes area.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_clip_on):

> `set_clip_on(b)`
>
> Set whether artist uses clipping.
>
> When `False` artists will be visible out side of the axes which can lead to unexpected results

for your example:

```
input_spec,   = plt.plot(x, yTheo, color='#ee923b', lw=2, label='Input spectrum', clip_on=False)
samples_spec, = plt.plot(x, ySamples, 'o', ms=1, color='k', label='Samples', clip_on=False)
```